# How to set a custom JSON Serializer in Refit

Tags: uwp, refit

Currently the API response includes two top level attributes which are of no use to my need.

```
a: {
   b: {
      c: [
           data: whichINeed
         ]
      }
   }
```

If I create models for this I would have unncessary root objects which I want to get rid of ?
How can I do this in Refit for Windows App ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer` that exists on package `Refit.Newtonsoft.Json`.

Then, add it to the RefitSettings:

```
RestService.For<T>("host"),
  new RefitSettings
  {
    ContentSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer(jsonSerializerSettings)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering the JSON string using `Newtonsoft.JSON` nuget package.

The JSON you provided is incomplete. I assume that this JSON string is an `Object` and the outermost layer is `{}`, then we can parse it like this

```cs
var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var c = obj["a"]["b"]["c"];
var myTransferModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(c.ToString());
```

If the outermost layer is `[]`, please use `JArray` for parsing.

---

**Update**

`Refit` encapsulating the network request and JSON parsing. You can send a web request directly through `HttpClient` to get a JSON string.

```cs
public async Task<string> GetJsonString(string url)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.GetAsync(url);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: I am using [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit), how would I obtain a Json String ? Am sorry, am new to this I couldnt understand that part.